# Backport android.graphics.Camera.setLocation() functionality

Tags: android, graphics, matrix

In my code I need to reduce default perspective of `android.graphics.Camera`. According to official API, by default its position is set to (0,0,-8), but I can use the method [`setLocation(float,float,float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html#setLocation%28float,%20float,%20float%29) in order to step back the point-of-view to (0, 0, -24) and consequently reduce the skewing effect.

Unfortunately such a method is available only for API 12+ and Romain Guy confirmed on twitter I have to set matrix values by hand to get the same result without using that convenience method. So (if I'm not wrong), I have to generate my own matrix and concatenate it with the one I get from `Camera` object.

`Camera` class unfortunately is not pure Java, but a simple JNI wrapper for native `SkCamera3D` class implemented into Skia 2D framework ([SkCamera.h](https://code.google.com/p/skia/source/browse/trunk/include/utils/SkCamera.h) and [SkCamera.cpp](https://code.google.com/p/skia/source/browse/trunk/src/utils/SkCamera.cpp)).

Digging into the code I found out that the matrix held within this class can be represented as follows:

```
|  scaleX  skewX   transX  |
|  skewY   scaleY  transY  |
|  persp0  persp1  persp2  |
```

but honestly I still can't understand all that tricky math inside the native code and I can't figure out how to change matrix values myself in order to get what I want.
Can anyone point me to some reference implementation or (even better) to some detailed explanation on how this kind of matrix works?